# Room Dao.java:19 error Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

I have been trying to implement Room Db to my already existing project using Hilt dependency but it seems that there is a problem with my Dao.java files. I tried deleting them for cleaning up but it didn't work out. Here are the Build Logs :

> /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/dao/CardDao.java:19:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
> kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
> ^ /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/dao/CardDao.java:17:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
> public abstract java.lang.Object insert(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
> ^ /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/dao/CardDao.java:29:
> error: Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently
> the supported return types are void, int or Int.
> public abstract java.lang.Object delete(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
> ^ /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/dao/CardDao.java:31:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
> kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
> ^ /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/dao/CardDao.java:25:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
> kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> $completion);
> ^ /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/dao/CardDao.java:23:
> error: Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently
> the supported return types are void, int or Int.
> public abstract java.lang.Object update(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull
> ^ /Users/bartu/AndroidStudioProjects/YuGiOhCards/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/yugiohcards/data/db/CardDatabase.java:10:
> warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation
> processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide
> `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set
> exportSchema to false. public abstract class CardDatabase extends
> androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
> ^
>
> > Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED AAPT2 aapt2-8.0.2-9289358-osx Daemon #0: shutdown
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

**Dao Class**

```
@Dao
       interface CardDao {
           @Insert
           suspend fun insert(cardBill: CardBill)
           @Update
           suspend fun update(cardBill: CardBill)
           @Delete
           suspend fun delete(cardBill: CardBill)
           @Query("SELECT * FROM card_table ORDER BY name")
           fun getAll(): Flow<List<CardBill>>
       }
```

**Entity Class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "card_table")
data class CardBill(
    @PrimaryKey val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    val price: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl")
    val imageUrl: String)


@Database(entities = [CardBill::class], version = 1)
abstract class CardDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun cardDao(): CardDao
}
interface CardNetworkRepo {
    suspend fun getNetwork(): Call<CardResponse>

    suspend fun searchCard(name: String): Call<CardResponse>

}
```

**Repo and Hilt Implementation**

```
interface CardDbRepo {
    suspend fun insert(cardBill: CardBill)

    suspend fun update(cardBill: CardBill)

    suspend fun delete(cardBill: CardBill)

    fun getAll(): Flow<List<CardBill>>
}

class CardRepoImplementation @Inject constructor(private val api: CardApi) : CardNetworkRepo {
    override suspend fun getNetwork() = api.getBlueEyes()

    override suspend fun searchCard(name: String): Call<CardResponse> = api.searchCards(name)

}

class CardDbImplementation @Inject constructor(private val cardDao: CardDao) : CardDbRepo {
    override suspend fun insert(cardBill: CardBill) = cardDao.insert(cardBill)

    override suspend fun update(cardBill: CardBill) = cardDao.update(cardBill)

    override suspend fun delete(cardBill: CardBill) = cardDao.delete(cardBill)

    override fun getAll(): Flow<List<CardBill>> = cardDao.getAll()
}

    )
    @Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMyApi(): CardApi {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(CardApi::class.java)
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMyRepo(api: CardApi): CardNetworkRepo {
        return CardRepoImplementation(api)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCardDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): CardDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            CardDatabase::class.java,
            "card_table"
        ).build()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideCardDao(database: CardDatabase): CardDao {
        return database.cardDao()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCardDbRepo(cardDao : CardDao): CardDbRepo {
        return CardDbImplementation(cardDao)
    }
}
```

Comment: provideCardDao method should not be @Singleton since CardDatabase is a singleton already. This might be a problem.

Comment: I removed the Singleton annotation it still gives me the same problem. Maybe there is a problem with my Kotlin version

Comment: Yes. Dependencies are the most annoying problem. I can give you my versions, you can check if they will work. Room: 2.5.1, Kotlin: 1.8.20-RC.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I got it, the problem was the kap dependency turns out that Google is now suggesting to use ksp instead. So if anyone is having the same problem migrate from kap to ksp

Answer (score -1):

Try to related questions variants. - I think they can help you.
And try to clean project - invalidate and restart with clear file system cache.

Comment: I tried them, it seems like it has something to do with my room and kotlin versions. I don't know whether if this is occurring only to my project but I wonder if room 2.5.2 and kotlin 1.9.0 has a compatibility issue